# Get all the servers my bot is on using Discord API

Tags: discord

I have a Discord bot added to a few servers/guilds. I'm able to get a specific guild using the resources available here:
https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild

It's fairly simple, requiring me to send a GET request to `https://discordapp.com/api/guilds/{guildID}`. What I want to do is get a list of all the guilds that my bot is connected to using the API. Haven't been able to find anything referencing that in the docs. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you aren't using `discord.py`, `discord.js`, or other similar libraries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For sure it's possible, you can directly interect with the API like this:

```js
fetch('https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me/guilds', {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': token
  }
});
```

Also, you can find the documentation on https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-current-user-guilds